# New bioacoustics SE site may be of interest to you

Tags: discussion

The **Bioacoustics Stack Exchange** has reached the Beta stage and is LIVE! It is also in a critical stage, and we need your help to keep it alive.  It is related to the Biology SE, but really different at the same time, so you may be interested to join!

We have only 2 weeks to prove we have the community to support the site! Please help as you can!

How can you help?

- **JOIN**: https://bioacoustics.stackexchange.com/
  **VISIT**: Make it a habit to check in on the site regularly. We need >>500 visits per day!
- **VOTE**: We need to show participation! Vote on all good Q/A
- **ASK**: Have a new bioacoustics-related question? What about your older questions? You can even ask/answer your own question! These questions will be archived for future use, so ALL good questions are welcome! We need >> 10 questions per day!
- **ANSWER**: Have an answer to one of the questions, or additional information? Share your expertise where you can! Is there a question you are often asked? You can pair up with someone to ask/answer it again to be archived! If someone asks you a question-- tell them you will answer it on the Stack Exchange! We need ~2.5 answers per question.
- **INVITE & SHARE**: Invite others to join! Share on social media, with your collaborators, etc.!
- **DISCUSS** the proposed site at the Meta page to suggest features and get help

**DO NOT DELAY!** Participate today and every day that you can. We know our community can support a site, but it takes time to create this habit. Unfortunately, this proposal has a deadline and we need ALL the help we can get, as often as possible!

**Why do we need a SE site in Bioacoustics?**

Because it is one of the fastest growing fields in both marine and terrestrial science. It gives us a unique opportunity to observe animal behavior and track populations’ distribution non-invasively.  Additionally, if done correctly, it can be easier and cheaper to collect data than traditional survey techniques. Most bioacoustic equipment is several thousand dollars/euros, sure, but that equipment can be left unattended, collecting data, ranging from weeks to months. This makes it more accessible to a larger group of researchers, and smaller companies are cropping up to make the startup costs even cheaper. However, analyzing that data can be a headache. You can find yourself with terabytes of acoustic data, and not know what to do with it.

**But I’m not an expert, so this doesn’t sound like it’s for me.**

We need folks from ALL walks of life! We need experts, yes, but we also need enthusiastics, students, related professionals, and folks that are just curious.  We need folks asking questions that those of us conducting research wouldn’t think to ask in addition to the folks that can answer those questions.

So please, check it out, and join us! And if you have questions, you can reach out to bioacousticsse@gmail.com or shannon.rankin@noaa.gov.

Comment: Well, it seems very specialized to me, but if there is the audience for it I wish you luck.